# Unable to add Kotlin Android Extensions to my android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, kotlin-multiplatform

hen i try to add kotlin-android-extensions via:

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

to my project Android Studio tells me Plugin with 'kotlin-android-extensions not found??

What is going wrong? I am Running Android Studio

Answer (score 2):

**It's deprecated Base on the [google document](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration)**

> Kotlin Android Extensions is deprecated, which means that using Kotlin
> synthetics for view binding is no longer supported.

for those who's wonder what the `synthetic` is. I should say a simple way to access to UI view id with kotlin which was possible by adding `'kotlin-android-extensions'` in `Gradle`.

- If your app uses Parcelable you can use `'kotlin-parcelize'` instead of `'kotlin-android-extensions'`.
- If your app uses Kotlin synthetics for view binding, use this guide to migrate to Jetpack [ViewBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) or [Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding).

you can add any of it like the following

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        dataBinding true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Kotlin Android Extensions has been deprecated for two years and should not be used in new products.

[As of Kotlin 1.8, it is not available at all anymore.](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2022/02/discontinuing-kotlin-synthetics-for-views.html)

I don't think they've officially turned it off yet, since Kotlin 1.8 hasn't officially been released, so there is probably some config issue in your project's Gradle files, but it doesn't matter, because you should not rely on a plugin that is going to stop working within 3 months.

Answer (score 1):

As "kotlin-android-extensions" is deprecated now, it's better to use view binding.
just head to the module-level build.gradle and add inside the android block:

```
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
```

then you will be able to use binding variables to reference views from your activities and fragments, all you need is [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding), but if you have any additonal questions to viewBinding just leave a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
Following steps helps in managing the view binding for fragments :

 1. Remove 'Kotlin-android-extensions' from the plugin.

 2. add the below code in your app/build.gradle :

android {
     ...
     buildFeatures {
         viewBinding true
     }
 }

 3. Add the below code in your app/build.gradle file
 android{
.......
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
           
        }
}
    }
```